# Mac Slave - connect to Master on restart

Tags: macos, jenkins, launchd, master-slave

I have Jenkins master running in Windows server 2012.

I have some windows slaves. Connected via JNLP. There is also a Windows Service running in those slaves.
So even if I restart windows slaves - they get connected to master once it is up. Awesome!!

I also have a MAC slave. Currently connecting this via Java Web start. I need something like 'Windows Service' for mac. I heard of 'launchd'
But it does not seem to connect to master automatically when I restart the MAC machine. This is what I need!!!

I also tried with RunAtLoad as True, KeepAlive as True in the LaunchDaemon. It does not help at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My only issue was to start the launchDaemon during start up. I did not know how to do it. At last i figured it out by creating an executable to launchDaemon and to invoke the exe from /etc/launchd.conf during start up.  It works great now.

Answer (score 4):

It's built in in The Jenkins JNLP on mac; just install it as a Service :

[image]
[image]

Comment: What!!? Is this from when? I never saw this option..i will try & let you know

Comment: this method no longer works on macos Mojave v10.14.4

Answer (score 4):

Create com.jenkins.slave.plist in /Library/LaunchAgents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.jenkins.slave</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>/usr/bin/java</string>
                <string>-jar</string>
                <string>/Users/jenkins/slave.jar</string>
                <string>-jnlpUrl</string>
                <string>https://YOUR_JENKINS/computer/mac-os-x/slave-agent.jnlp</string>
                <string>-noCertificateCheck</string>
                <string>-secret</string>
                <string>YOUR_SECRET</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <true/>
        <key>StandardOutPath</key>
        <string>/Users/jenkins/stdout.log</string>
        <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
        <string>/Users/jenkins/error.log</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Then, update YOUR_JENKINS and YOUR_SECRET credentials, and load service via:

```
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/com.jenkins.slave.plist
```

On next login, your slave will automatically connect to the Jenkins Master.

Comment: The `-noCertificateCheck` argument should not be necessary if your Jenkins installation has SSL.

Comment: Also remember to change `/Users/jenkins` to the home directory of your user, if you are using something other than `jenkins` as the username.

Comment: hi @amacleod running with latest macos. Setup with all your sugesstion but when load the plist, i got error: `Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /": Read-only file system`

Comment: same here. Any ideas how to fix that? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could give this a try [jenkins-slave-osx](https://github.com/rhwood/jenkins-slave-osx)

> Jenkins Slave for OS X Scripts to create and run a Jenkins slave via
>   Java Web Start (JNLP) on OS X as a Launch Daemon.
>
> Quick Start
>
> bash <( curl -L
>   https://raw.github.com/rhwood/jenkins-slave-osx/master/install.sh )

Comment: I was really excited after seeing this. But it fails At the step. "Unable to authenticate <user> with this API token". I ensured that i typed correctly.